# Opening Settings Application

Tags: ios, application-settings, iphone-privateapi

Would the following be considered as private API use? After googling I have found many conflicting reports.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs://"]];
```

Also does anyone have a list of valid urls within the settings application? For example:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs://notifications"]];
```

will open the notifications page of the settings application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to my own question.

It is supported in iOS5.
URL Schemes can be found here: http://maniacdev.com/2011/11/tutorial-using-url-schemes-to-open-the-settings-app-to-a-specific-page-in-ios-5/

Comment: Note that it's not been possible any longer since the release of iOS 5.1.

Comment: Did you found anything else for later versions of iOS?